# Como calculo determinante de uma matriz quadrada em python?

Tags: python-3.x, matriz

Meu arquivo está assim:

```
arq = open('matriz.txt', 'r')  
texto = []  
matriz = [] 
texto = arq.readlines() 


for i in range(len(texto)):         
    matriz.append(texto[i].split())  


for i in range(len(texto)):         
    print(matriz[i])  


arq.close()
```

Comment: Poderia postar o conteúdo do arquivo de entrada `matriz.txt` também ?

Comment: seria um arquivo tipo assim 10#10#10

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o pacote [`NumPy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), que possui uma [larga coleção de funções](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.html) matemáticas capazes de trabalhar com matrizes multidimensionais.

Para se computar a determinante de uma matriz você pode usar a função [`numpy.linalg.det()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html), veja só:

```
import numpy

matriz = [ [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3] ]

print( numpy.linalg.det( matriz ) )
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ChillyAltruisticNanocad)

Para ler a matriz a partir de um arquivo e calcular a sua determinante:

```
import numpy

matriz = []

with open('matriz.txt', 'r')  as f:
    for linha in f.readlines():
      matriz.append( [ float(i) for i in linha.split() ] )

determ = numpy.linalg.det( matriz )

print(matriz)
print(determ)
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ColorfulJoyousEmbed).

Ou, simplesmente:

```
import numpy

with open('matriz.txt', 'r')  as f:
    matriz = [[ float(i) for i in linha.split()] for linha in f.readlines()]

determ = numpy.linalg.det( matriz )

print(matriz)
print(determ)
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DarkgrayLividPhysics).

Comment: Eu não posso usar o numpy infelizmente.